# How do I round numbers in KDB?

Tags: kdb

It looks like I can hack `floor` and `ceiling` into a meta function for an arbitrary `round`, but is there a standard way to do:

```
round[3.1415;2] = 3.14
```

from the core functions?

Edit: This is problem I'm trying to solve:

I have unadjusted daily stock data, and I'm trying to identify splits and filter them out. It's further complicated by decimalisation artefacts (a split might not be perfectly 2:1 because prices have minimum tick sizes).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no standard way because in kdb you shouldn't ever really need to round floats. What's the reason to round floats? If it's just for pretty-printing displays then you can use a method like Matthew suggests, but underlying kdb logic shouldn't need it.

If you must, you can use floor/ceiling as you've already figured out or you can use the built-in nearest-rounding that casting to interger/long achieves. E.g.

```
q)d:{("j"$x*y)%x}
q)d2:d[100]
q)d3:d[1000]
q)
q)a:5?10.0
q)
q)d2 a
3.92 0.81 9.37 2.78 2.39
q)d3 a
3.915 0.812 9.368 2.782 2.392
```

But even here you should be aware that this is completely fictional rounding because you're still using floats and still subject to floating point fuzziness. If I increase the precision value those same results above are:

```
q)\P 18
q)
q)d2 a
3.9199999999999999 0.81000000000000005 9.3699999999999992 2.7799999999999998 ..
q)d3 a
3.915 0.81200000000000006 9.3680000000000003 2.782 2.3919999999999999
```

The only way to have a truly concrete number of decimal places is to store the whole numbers as ints/longs and separately store the decimals as ints/longs

Comment: Thanks for this. I agree this is the right answer (even if it doesn't actually solve the issue); I'll have to try a smarter way of looking at my data. I've added some extra details above for what I'm trying to do, just in case it's of interest. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Ok. In your use case I would multiply those numbers by some power of 10, say `100000000000` and cast to long either by using floor/ceiling or `"j"$`.....then if those longs are equal then you consider them the same original number. You can adjust your degree of acceptable accuracy by adjusting the power of 10 but note that there's a maximum limit for long numbers so you need to ensure you don't spill over that when multiplying by such a large number

Comment: calculating medians (eg med spreads) across partitions might involve rounding to some lower precision and counting each observation. then accumulating each partition and finding the middle value. This is a legit use of rounding in core kdb logic, that has nothing to do with display.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible via the use of [.Q.f](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qf-format), this does however return the output as a string.

Using this we can round 3.14159 to 2 decimal places like so:

```
q) .Q.f[2;] 3.14
"3.14"
q)round:{"F"$.Q.f[y]x}
q)round[3.1415;2]
3.14
```