# Function to Convert decimals to percentage in KDB

Tags: kdb, q

```
`pct:157.35686
func[`pct]
func::{[x]
    ?[x>1;x-100;100*x]}
```

The result should be as 57.35%

```
`pct:0.804892
func[`pct]
func::{[x]
    ?[x>1;x-100;100*x]}
```

The result should be as 80.48%

Comment: Looks like you also want the result rounded down to two decimal places.

Comment: SJT and Maurice have you covered but I don't understand your logic. If `pct` are both decimals I would think `157.35 = 15735%`. What % would 250 be? 150%?

Comment: Yeah the function and the question is weird. To convert decimals to percentage you only need to multiply the decimals by 100 and (format it and) add a % sign like what Matt suggested. If I understood what you are trying to do correctly, you probably need something like x mod 100 for numbers more than 100?

Comment: Yes true @MauriceLim, x mod 100 could works but,  
`pct[137.5792]
pct:{[x]
    ?[x>=100;x mod 100;x*100]}`

My but result should be 37.57% instead of 37.5792% percision only upto 2 decimal places

Comment: @coderinq for converting it into 2DP - you could combine it with SJT's answer or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68759384/how-do-i-round-numbers-in-kdb provides a good solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of [Vector Conditional](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/vector-conditional) `?` suggests your argument might be a vector†.

```
q){?[x>1;x-100;x*100]} 157.35686 0.804892
57.35686 80.4892
```

The specimen answers are [rounded down](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/xbar) to two decimal places.

```
q).01 xbar {?[x>1;x-100;x*100]} 157.35686 0.804892
57.35 80.48
```

The specimen answers are suffixed with percentage signs: cast them to strings. Project [Join](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/join) onto `"%"` to derive unary `,[;"%"]` which you can apply with `each`.

```
q),[;"%"] each string .01 xbar {?[x>1;x-100;x*100]}157.35686 0.804892
"57.35%"
"80.48%"
```

---

† For an atom argument use the ‘ternary conditional’ control structure [Cond](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cond).

```
q){$[x>1;x-100;x*100]}157.35686
57.35686
q){$[x>1;x-100;x*100]}0.804892
80.4892
```

Why? Because Vector Conditional is an operator and all three of its arguments are evaluated. That is, whatever the result of `x>1`, **both** `x-100` and `x*100` are evaluated. With Cond, either the second or third expression is evaluated; never both.

In this example, the cost is of course negligible. In other cases the expressions in the second and third arguments could be expensive.

Answer (score 1):

```
`pct:157.35686
```

is wrong because you are not assigning a variable.

```
func:{[x]
    ?[x>1;x-100;100*x]}
pct:0.804892
func[pct]
pct:157.35686
func[pct]
```

should work for your case. I removed the global assign for the function as well.